# Pick 2 random values from a set of constants

Tags: prolog

In Prolog, how do I randomly pick 2 values from a set of 52 cards? i.e. Player1(X,Y), X will be any card out of 52 and Y another and they have to be different. Player2 will get the same treatment and his cards must differ from the ones already picked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog I would do a pick_card/3

```
pick_card(Cards, Card, Rest) :-
  length(Cards, N), random_between(1, N, R), nth1(R, Cards, Card, Rest).
```

and apply it 2 times

```
pick_two_cards(Cards, C1,C2, Rest) :-
  pick_card(Cards, C1, R1),
  pick_card(R1, C2, Rest).
```

Comment: Wow!Interesting enouth. The only part it's not clear to me is the predicate nth1. If I am not wrong it associates Card to the random number found. If so then why is Rest there?

Comment: Just to keep pick_card *reusable*. Adding input/output Cards/Rest you can reuse in a wider context. Otherwise, just 'drop' unwanted output argument - a so called projection...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the task is to sample 4 different elements from set [1..52].

In Python, for example, there is a standard function for this, and the code would be

```
random.sample(range(1, 52 + 1), 4)
```

I've looked how Python implements `random.sample(range(1..N + 1), K)` - it's basically just K steps of generating random numbers [1..N], and on every step just keep trying generate random numbers while currently generated number already selected in a previous step. It looks inefficient, but it's probably needed to archive uniformity of the distribution.

Let's create a similar (but simplified) `sample` predicate for Prolog.

```
sample(N, K, Sample) :-
    sample(N, K, [], Sample).

sample(_, 0, _, []).
sample(N, K, Selected, [X | Rest]) :-
    K > 0,
    new_random_index(N, Selected, X),
    NewSelected = [X | Selected],
    NewK is K - 1,
    sample(N, NewK, NewSelected, Rest).

new_random_index(N, Selected, X) :-
    ( 
        % Can be implementation-specific. Works in B-Prolog and ECLiPSe CLP.
        X is (random mod N) + 1, 
        \+ membchk(X, Selected) 
    ; 
        new_random_index(N, Selected, X)
    ).
```

Couple of test runs:

```
| ?- sample(52, 4, Sample).
sample(52, 4, Sample).
Sample = [40,23,38,44] ?
yes
| ?- sample(52, 4, Sample).
sample(52, 4, Sample).
Sample = [2,28,39,17] ?
yes
```

Efficiency of the program can be greatly improved if `membchk` test changed to a predicate that test membership using sets, not lists. But this is very implementation-specific.

Comment: Sergey this is way too complex for me. Hope in the next future I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw random cards repeatedly, it is probably best to shuffle the whole list in one go, and then simply pick cards from the front.  Some Prologs (e.g. [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/)) have a library predicate for this, so you could just call

```
lists:shuffle(Cards, [Card1,Card2|Rest]).
```

If you want to write the shuffling yourself, here is a neat trick:

```
shuffle(Xs, Rs) :-
    add_random_keys(Xs, KXs),  % add random key to each list element
    keysort(KXs, KRs),         % sort by keys, perturbing original order
    strip_keys(KRs, Rs).       % remove the keys again

add_random_keys([], []).
add_random_keys([X|Xs], [K-X|KXs]) :-
    random(K),
    add_random_keys(Xs, KXs).

strip_keys([], []).
strip_keys([_K-X|KXs], [X|Xs]) :-
    strip_keys(KXs, Xs).
```